# A short noun equivalent to "non-applicability"

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a shorter version of the noun "non-applicability" to complete the following triplet.

**Truth** is to true as **Falsity** is to false as **X** is to na.

What should **X** be?

Non-applicability has the correct meaning, but I want to find a shorter but equivalent word. For background, I'm writing a programming library and I have subprograms with names corresponding to the names of the above triplet. However, programmers hate long names so I need to find a shorter version of the last subprogram name.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps *inapplicable*? Or just use *na*, for *not applicable*.

Comment: both would be good choices but I'm pretty set on using a noun.

Comment: *N/A* is a noun when it is used as "null".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps **[irrevelance](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/irrelevance)**

> the quality or state of not relating to or being pertinent to the matter at hand; unimportance

The term is often used dismissively, but that is not intrinsic to the meaning.

Comment: that's an interesting use of the word. Thank you very much, that finishes the triplet perfectly!